# Read a CSV file in Python and print out unique dates from a column that has date and time

Tags: python

I need to be able to read a csv file and sum a few columns per day and then generate a new csv file with the solutions. I am brand new to Python and I have figured out how to read the csv but now I must figure out how to sum the columns based on the date/time column.

CSV:

```
tag,date,symbol,exch,volume,price,side,ind
1058,20140612 13:29:59.042,BRK/B,NQBX,1000,61.25,SELL_SHORT,A
1059,20140612 13:29:59.043,JNJ,NQBX,185,31.94,SELL_SHORT,A
1153,20140612 13:30:00.117,AAPL,NQBX,77,43.64,SELL,A
1201,20140612 13:30:00.190,WFC,NQBX,100,49.92,SELL,A
1720,20140612 13:30:04.003,JPM,NQBX,100,50.16,SELL,A
1738,20140613 13:30:04.254,PFE,NQBX,600,43.89,SELL_SHORT,A
108167,20140613 13:30:04.809,VZ,NSDQ,2000,61.23,SELL_SHORT,R
1799,20140613 13:30:05.252,MSFT,NQBX,11,43.76,BUY,A
1879,20140612 13:30:06.393,CVX,NQBX,40,70.58,BUY,A
1908,20140612 13:30:06.803,INTC,NQBX,100,56.52,SELL_SHORT,A
1989,201406117 13:30:08.003,GE,NQBX,100,50.14,SELL,A
2008,20140619 13:30:08.169,JNJ,NQBX,97,15.18,SELL,A
2021,20140619 13:30:08.393,PFE,NQBX,38,43.89,SELL_SHORT,A
2197,20140619 13:30:10.599,WFC,NQBX,100,30.34,BUY,A
2302,20140620 13:30:12.002,GE,NQBX,100,50.14,SELL,A
2368,20140620 13:30:12.931,INTC,NQBX,500,31.44,SELL,A
```

I need to sum the volume column per day and then create a new csv with the summary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `csv.DictReader` with `itertools.groupby` to achieve what you want.

```
import csv
import itertools

def sum_volumes_by_date(yourcsvfile, writetocsv):
    # it will read all your data and pairing the header to values into a dictionary
    results = [line for line in csv.DictReader(open(yourcsvfile))]

    with open(writetocsv, 'w') as f:    
        f.write("Date,Sum(Vols)\n")

        # use groupby to group a sorted list of the dictionary by its 'date'
        for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(results, key=lambda x: x['date']), \
                                      lambda each: each['date'][:8]):
            # then sum its relative 'volume' values
            f.write("{},{}\n".format(k, sum([int(each['volume']) for each in g])))
```

Usage:

```
>>> sum_volumes_by_date('in.csv', 'out.csv')
>>> cat out.csv
Date,Sum(Vols)
20140611,100
20140612,1602
20140613,2611
20140619,235
20140620,600
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily using dictionaries, check out this example:

```
import csv

with open('csv.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:

    # initiate csv reader
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)   

    # initiate empty dictionary
    daily_volumes = {}

    # iterate through each column
    for row in csv_reader:
        # attempt to add to an existing date key (this will fail the first time we get a new date)
        try:
            # add the new volume to this day
            daily_volumes[row[1].split(' ')[0]] += int(row[4])
        except KeyError:
            try:
                # this date does not exist as a key yet, so now we create it
                daily_volumes[row[1].split(' ')[0]] = int(row[4])
            except ValueError:
                # the header will error out on the int() function, so just skip it
                pass

    # This will give us a dictionary like so:
    '''
    daily_volumes = {
        '20140619': 235, 
        '20140612': 1602, 
        '20140613': 2611, 
        '201406117': 100, 
        '20140620': 600
    }
    '''

    # Now create a new CSV and write these values to it
    with open('new_csv.csv', 'wb') as new_csv_file:
        # initiate csv writer
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_csv_file)

        # write each key as a row
        for date, volume in daily_volumes.iteritems():
            csv_writer.writerow([date, volume])
```